# Is statement.close() explicitly required in connection pooled environment?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, connection-pooling

I am using connection pooling in my application. My question is:

Is it explicitly required to close statement before closing connection in case of connection pooled environment?

In connection pooled environment connection is not getting closed, (but returns back to free connection pool).
I had checked jdbc 4.0 functional specs. In point number 9.4.4, it clearly states that :

> Closing Connection Objects An application calls the method Connection.close to indicate that it has finished  using a connection. All Statement objects created from a given Connection object  will be closed when the close method for the object is called.  Once a Connection has been closed, any attempt to access any of its methods with  the exception of the close, isClosed or isValid methods will result in a  SQLException being thrown.

So jdbc specs mandates closing all statement at a time of closing connection. So is it applicable to only non connection pooled environment  only or it applies to connection pooled environment also ?

According to me it should not matter in case of pooled environment, because we are coding for interface (`java.sql.Connection` & `java.sql.Statement`). So we are not bothering about implementation and parent class (`java.sql.Connection`) doesn't have any information about child/impementation class (Vendor implementation class).

Comment: If jdbc specs mandates to all implementation to close statement at a time of closing connection, then we can easily skips statement.close method in case of we are using connection.close method (in connection pooled or non pooled environment).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any object which has close(), release(), destroy(), etc, suggests automatically(of course you should read the API documentation, there might be different names used for this purpose) that the object needs an invoke of this method to ensure that the object resources are released when the object is not in use anymore.There will be no reason to provide such a method if the object can do that by itself.

In case of pooled java.sql.Connection, the connection is not really closed, is just pushed back in the pool as *available* connection but this is *internal stuff* aka *you should not care*.

Comment: I agree that you should not care, as long as the pooled connection adheres to the contract defined by the documentation (i.e. that closing the connection also closes any associated statements). However, in the absence of such a guarantee, you unfortunately DO need to care.

Answer (score 7):

Absolutely. It's possible that the `Statement` implementation will have other resources which should be released, or have some other relationship with the connection. You don't, and shouldn't, know the implementation details.

Your approach is absolutely right: code to the interface and avoid little "short-cuts" which could easily bite you later. (Even if it works now, it might not in a future version of the pool or connection classes.)

Comment: The other students in my database class in college can attest to the importance of calling .close.  My application neglected to call close and ended up creating lots of lingering connections on the DB server.  So much so that it started preventing new connections from being created.  The night before the project was due.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, some JDBC drivers have bugs.  They seem to work best if you close all Statements (and ResultSets) manually.  Otherwise I have seen resource leaks that shouldn't have persisted past the closing of the Connection.